# How to make a newline without autoindent

Tags: indentation

Is there a command to make a newline *without* the autoindent? In other words, I want `o` and `O` to normally autoindent, but is there another command that will not autoindent for just the duration of that command?

Alternatively (if there isn't a way to that exactly), what's a better workaround than just backspacing a ton after autoindenting many tabs too far.

---

#### Example

```
if some_check():
    self.some_long_function_name(withlots, ofargs
                                 andmaybe=keywordargs)
                               # ^ Indents to the caret
```

Pressing `o` on the `andmaybe=keywordargs` line leaves me *way* more indented than I want to be.

Comment: You seem to have some special indent settings. For me `andmaybe` is indented 8 chars (double shiftwidth). When I hit `o`, the cursor is aligned with `self`. This even works when I indent `andmybe` manually to align it with the open paranthesis. BTW: Vim 8.1.1223

Comment: It's probably a Python plugin that indents it like this? This indenting style is fairly common in Python. As for the question, what does "without the autoindent" mean for you? That it starts at column 0? Anything other than that would be using some form of autoindent (just a different one that what you get right now).

Comment: Python [indent script](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/indent/python.vim) was last updated in February.

Comment: I'm not using anything special for Python.

Comment: Is there an indentation to start at column 0? That would be better than what I'm doing

Comment: When I hit `o` on `andmaybe`, it lines me up right under the `a` in `and`.

Comment: Does it work better if you start Vim with `vim --clean file.py` ?

Comment: @Ralf Yes. If I `o` at `andmaybe` after making clean, it sets me under the `s` in `self`. So it's probably something weird in my vimrc then, right?

Comment: Yes, it is something in your vimrc. You should [Debug your vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file).

Comment: @Ralf That’s the behaviour of `autoindent`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is an normal mode command to start a new line without indent. You can, however, *remove* the indent while in insert mode with the keystrokes <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>, and so it's easy to set up new mappings to do so:

```
nnoremap <leader>o o0<C-D>
nnoremap <leader>O O0<C-D>
```

Personally, though, I'd install an indent plugin to handle this for you*.

I use [vim-python-pep8-indent](https://github.com/Vimjas/vim-python-pep8-indent.git) which handles your example nicely.

<sub>Or indeed, just use the Python indent script included in Vim (via the `:filetype` command) instead of the `'autoindent'` setting. This is the one @Ralf [describes in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19798/how-to-make-a-newline-without-autoindent/19800#comment34558_19798).</sub>